# Semaphore execution with 4 processes

Tags: java, c, operating-system

Can any one please explain this for me?

In the following code, four processes produce output using `printf` and synchronize using three semaphores `R`, `S` and `T`. We assume `printf` won’t cause context switch.

```
/* initialization */
Semaphore R=1, S = 3, T = 0;

/* process 1 */
while(true) { 
    P(S);
    printf('A');
}

/* process 2 */  
while(true) {   
    P(T);  
    printf('B');
    printf('C');
    V(T); 
}

/* process 3 */
while(true) {   
    P(T); 
    printf('D');
    V(R);  
}

/*process 4 */     
while(true) { 
   P(R);      
   printf('E');       
   V(T);  
}
```

How many A's and B's are printed when this set of processes runs?

Comment: Please format your code.  Also is this `c` or `java`?

Comment: It is kind of pseudo code

Comment: Seriously! it is hard to read and understand what you are talking about. Please have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I guess the first thing you need to figure out is what `P()` and `V()` do.

Comment: There are no inter-process semaphores in Java. Do you mean 'thread'? Or is the [tag:java] tag an error?

Comment: P() permit and V() wait

Comment: And what does `permit` mean?

Comment: I know it will print 3 A's for sure, but I don't know how many times will print B's

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)#Operation_names

Comment: I am confused because I know there is 2 types of semaphore which are binary and counting, so in my case it consider counting, Right????

Comment: Yes, `S` has to be a counting semaphore, and you are correct that `A` will print 3 times. `R` and `T` could either be counting or binary semaphores, but let's assume that they are counting semaphores.

Comment: Thanks a lot. About D, it will print 1 at least, right?? because it pass 0 and wait for 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Process 1 has nothing to do with another processes, since it just acquires S, and releases nothing. It will print 'A' 3 times, and will sleep forever.

Process 2 & 3 will be sleep immediately on starting, because T source is not available to acquire at starting. Process 4 will acquire last R and will release a T. This release will awake process 2 or 3. On next loop, process 4 will sleep because there are no R left.

So far, we have: R=0, S = 0, T = 1

Let's say T's release awakened Process 2, then it will acquire back the T, print 'BC', and will release back a T. This release will awake sleeping Process 3. In next loop, process 2 will sleep, because Process 3 acquired the T.

Process 3 will use T, will print a 'D', and will release a R. This release of R will put 2nd, 3rd and 4th processes to infinite loop. Because R and T never will be acquired completely at the same time.

We can't know how many Bs will be printed, but we can say 'A' will be printed 3 times.